# Removing first set of numbers in string

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I have a list of items:

- B100Q91, B75NX2, BR100, XN20ZN..

I want to remove the first set of numbers in every item, so that it looks like this:

- BQ91, BNX2, BR, XNZN..

My approach looks like this:

```vb
Function RemoveFirstNumbers(Txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim posn As Integer
posn = GetPositionOfFirstNumericCharacter(Txt)
1
If (IsError(posn)) = True Then Replace(Txt, 1, 1) As String
Dim posn As Integer
Else
End With
End Function
End If
GoTo 1

with 

Public Function GetPositionOfFirstNumericCharacter(ByVal s As String) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Dim currentCharacter As String
        currentCharacter = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(currentCharacter) = True Then
            GetPositionOfFirstNumericCharacter = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Note that `vb.net` is not the same as `VBA` and you should tag `regexp` - I've made those changes for you.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT to package the below as a function

```
Function ReplaceFirstDigits(sLookupExpression) as String
    Dim oReg As Object

    Set oReg = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")

    With oReg
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)(\w*)"
    End With

    ReplaceFirstDigits = oReg.Replace(sLookupExpression, "$1$3")
End Function
```

Then you can call the function directly from the spreadsheet with a standard syntax, such as `=ReplaceFirstDigits(A1)`

If you wanted to use a regular expression, code such as the following might do the trick for you.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oReg As Object
    
    Set oReg = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    
    With oReg
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)(\w*)"
    End With
    
    Debug.Print oReg.Replace(Selection, "$1$3")

End Sub
```

Comment: You can simplify that with `.Global=False` and `.Pattern="\d+"`  `Multiline` is not needed. Your output would come from `.Replace(Selection, "")`  With `.Global=False`, only the first set of digits will be matched.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time. How can I call this macro in excel?

Comment: @Quant1337 You can create a function using the interior logic. Replace `Sub Test` with `Function Test` (or replace 'Test' with something more descriptive). Then return the value from the function. I'll make an edit to my post showing these changes.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

If you don't want to use RegExp, just straight VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Function RemoveFirstNumber(strInput As String) As String
    Dim strRet As String
    
    Dim bFirstNumber As Boolean
    bFirstNumber = False
    
    Dim strChar As String
    Dim nChar As Integer
    
    For nChar = 1 To Len(strInput)
        strChar = Mid(strInput, nChar, 1)
        
        If IsNumeric(strChar) Then
            bFirstNumber = True
        Else
            If bFirstNumber Then 
               strRet = strRet & Mid(strInput, nChar)
               Exit For
            End If
            
            strRet = strRet & strChar
        End If
    Next nChar
    
    RemoveFirstNumber = strRet
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi your code works, but only on some examples. Examples like BR100D, BRX100W, where only one letter is on the right side don't work - do you have an idea why?

Comment: @Quant1337 Ah yes ... didn’t test that case! I’ve edited the code, so hopefully this works better (not at my PC right now).